# Wordpress change image link url to file url

Tags: php, image, wordpress

When clicking on images in my posts it takes me to the attachment post of the image. From there I have to click the image again to get the full size. Instead I want to go directly to the full size image in uploads. Is there a function that will do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Media Upload, if you choose "File URL", it will link to the full-sized image.

If you want this to be the default behavior, you can either by changing the options directly in the dashboard, or by adding some code to your theme.

To do it by changing the option in the dashboard, visit this link for instructions:
http://blog.aizatto.com/2010/05/04/changing-default-wordpress-media-link-url/

To do it by adding some code to your theme, check out this article:
http://andrewnorcross.com/tutorials/functions-file/stop-hyperlinking-images/